# How to get the same text with error message in jsp page using servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and Servlet. I need your suggestion in following task. I have a jsp page which hava a html form which accepts some information from user.

**Jsp page:**

```
form method="post"  action="UpdateLinkPath">
<p><font color="red"><%if(request.getParameter("error")!=null) %>
<%=request.getParameter("error") %></font></p>
USER NAME:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="userName" value=${userName }
value="<c:out value= "${use.userName } " />" /><br>
FULL NAME:<input type="text"  name="fullName" value=${fullName } value="<c:out value="${use.fullName      } " />" /><br>
PASSWORD :<input type="password" name="password" value=${password } value="<c:out value="${use.password }"/>"/><br>
MOBILE   :<input type="text" name="mobile"  value=${mobile }value="<c:out value="${use.mobile }"/>"/><br>
E_MAIL   :<input type="text" name="email" value=${email } value="<c:out value="${use.email }"/>"/>  <br>

    <center><input type="submit" value="UPDATE"></center>
```

**Servlet:**

```
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String fullName = request.getParameter("fullName");
    String password= request.getParameter("password");
    String mobile= request.getParameter("mobile");
    String mail=request.getParameter("email");


    request.setAttribute("user", userName);
    request.setAttribute("mmm", mail);
    request.setAttribute("full", fullName);
    request.setAttribute("pass", password);
    request.setAttribute("mobile", mobile);
    // Perform operation
    RequestDispatcher dis = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(link);
    dis.forward(request, response);
```

As this client Upate information and submits the form the data in the form is set to UpdateLinkPath  which check whether the username entered by user is already exists in database. If username already exists then it sends the data back to the calling jsp and with an extra attribute that is "reply" and value as appropriate message. i.e. "user already exists " if entered user name is already exists in database or "user information saved successfully!" if data saved successfully.
I want to do something like that Whenever the username which is already exists is entered by user and form submitted then in this case the all data send back to the jsp should be get fill to their respective textbox. So that user can only enter the other username and submit this form again.

But it send back only the Username value. Remaining text box are empty.

How to achieve it?
 Thank you...

Comment: Look at your HTML: it's invalid: inputs have two value attributes, the attributes are not enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Yes, first value attribute is to display entered text along with error message , second value attribute is get the data from database and display it. if i add double quotes in first value attribute, the value coming from database is empty. could you pls explain with simple example..

Comment: You have to learn basics of HTML. An element can't have the same attribute twice.